# dompdf doesn't work on minify html (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, dompdf

Using hook in codeigniter I have minified my html. After doing that my pdf functionality is not working. I am using DOMPDF library for converting my HTML to PDF. Please Help me out.. Thank you

Comment: Add what code you are doing

Comment: // Compress output
$hook['display_override'][] = array(
    'class' => '',
    'function' => 'compress',
    'filename' => 'compress.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);

Comment: You'll need to expand on your question. For example, indicate how you are calling dompdf. Also, I personally am not familiar with how codeigniter hooks work, so you may want to indicate that it's doing what you expect by indicating how you're getting the output and that you have confirmed you are feeding the correct content to dompdf. Finally, if it's a dompdf problem you should provide a sample of the minified HTML?